# Why adding swap space is the slowest part of the booting process?

Tags: linux, performance, startup, swap

I can see that adding Swap space is the slowest part of the booting process. Why?

I actually have ~4GB for swap and 2GB RAM memory.

```
dione@saturno:~$ dmesg | grep -C 4 swap
[    2.179979] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
[    2.180061] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    2.180120] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    2.895482] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   17.840299] Adding 3999740k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3999740k 
[   18.438121] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   18.688222] EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   18.834834] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.047922] udevd[419]: starting version 175
```

These are the top ten delta times,

```
dione@saturno:~$ dmesg -d | cut -d "<" -f 2 | sort -nr | head
   14,944817>] Adding 3999740k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3999740k 
    8,241362>] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
    2,100332>] wlan0: authenticate with 64:70:02:a0:5d:28 (try 1)
    1,830923>] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1686) terminated with status 1
    0,973801>] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.4, id: 0x1e0b1, caps: 0xd04773/0xe40000/0xa0400
    0,715362>] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    0,597822>] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
    0,513048>] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
    0,318977>] init: failsafe main process (728) killed by TERM signal
```

**EDIT:** I think I keep having this issue,

```
...
[    3.271945] EXT4-fs (sda5): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.271949] EXT4-fs (sda5): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    4.220562] EXT4-fs (sda5): recovery complete
[    4.231392] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   90.312561] Adding 3905532k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3905532k FS
[   90.467351] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   90.772432] systemd-udevd[333]: starting version 204
[   91.146942] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   91.152406] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
...

dione@saturno:~$ LANG=us sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x793a8e8d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *   325117952   591443967   133163008    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       591443968   624928767    16742400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       624928768   625141759      106496    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda4            2046   325117951   162557953    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            2048    39064547    19531250   83  Linux
/dev/sda6        39065600    46876671     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7        46878720   325117951   139119616   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: You're only looking at the kernel logs. A lot of things may be happening that don't trigger a kernel log entry. It's likely that about 14.93 seconds are spent on things unrelated to swap. Use [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) to see what's going on.

Comment: Well, I'm not used to Unix, and I thought that `dmesg` was something like the master log. I'll try with bootchart